# Concatenating a list of Multi-indices pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a list whose elements are MultiIndex objects like:

```
MultiIndex([(48, 39),
        (48, 40),
        (48, 41),
        (48, 42),
        (48, 43),
        (49, 39),
        (49, 40),
        (49, 41),
        (49, 42),
        (49, 43)],
       )
MultiIndex([(48, 48),
            (48, 49),
            (49, 48),
            (49, 49)],
           )
```

I want to concatenate both, vertically, such that I have:

```
MultiIndex([(48, 39),
            (48, 40),
            (48, 41),
            (48, 42),
            (48, 43),
            (49, 39),
            (49, 40),
            (49, 41),
            (49, 42),
            (49, 43),
            (48, 48),
            (48, 49),
            (49, 48),
            (49, 49)],
           )
```

If possible, I would also like it to:

1. contain only unique pairs(but a,b is different from b,a )
2. and be ordered (the above is not ordered since two pairs starting with 48 show up after pairs with 49).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Union method to concatenate both of the MultiIndex Objects, and then set sort to True to sort it correctly:

```
#m1 is the first object and m2 is the second
result = m1.union(m2, sort=True)
```

This outputs:

```
MultiIndex([(48, 39),
            (48, 40),
            (48, 41),
            (48, 42),
            (48, 43),
            (48, 48),
            (48, 49),
            (49, 39),
            (49, 40),
            (49, 41),
            (49, 42),
            (49, 43),
            (49, 48),
            (49, 49)],
           )
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, however, your answer gives the following error: `TypeError: Must pass both levels and codes`.